# How to put self.navigationItem.titleView with title after replace it with searchbar in swift

Tags: swift, navigation, hide, title, searchbar

I have searchbar , when click image, it will create searchbar at top navigation , replace with title. Then when tap outside searchbar , the title don't show again , it still with searchbar (textfield), how to show again title if tap or click outside from searchbar ?

this is code to create searchBar at top navigation , replace with title.

```
func createSearchBar(){
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.placeholder = "Enter key"
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

This is code when tap outside searchbar

```
extension ViewCon {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewCon.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title="Title List"
}
```

}

But how i want show title on top navigation again ?

Comment: for a good question pls add code

Comment: i update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the to `nil`

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
```

see: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview

Comment: Thank it worked .. i spend time for it.. i already create new frame.. but your code just one line.. thanks a lot.. u saved my day..

Comment: u r welcome. just check also the search results at  [GitHub Search for: "navigationItem.titleView = nil" language:swift](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22navigationItem.titleView+%3D+nil%22+language%3Aswift&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Comment: i want ask one more question , i have tableview , when i scroll down and up again , image and label in cell will missing and disappear. u know why ?

Comment: please search stackoverflow or google and then create a new question :) i think your problem is in `cellforrowatindexpath`